# I want to update a field(Email_Address__c) on Quote object and pull that field from the Person Account (PersonalEmail)

Tags: process-builder

How would I build a process builder to do this?  [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: This is what I have so far.  I updated the process builder up top.